# How to fix "chown: invalid group:" if the user does not exist on the running system?

Tags: chown

I want to fix permissions on another disk with chown. Set the permissions to a user which does not exist on the system which is currently running.

Does that work without adding the user?

Comment: In my case, I was using chown with $USER:(id -n $USER) that fills the group. But the group had whitespaces so I had to surround the group part. $USER:"(id -n $USER)" worked for me

Answer (score 6):

Use the numerical UID/GID instead of the user/group name.

You can find the UID/GID on the system the disk belongs to by using

```
  id some_username
```

or

```
ls -ln some_file
```

where `some_file` is a file that belongs to user you are looking for

Assuming the Group ID is `100`, you can now recursively set ownership of a directory to this group ID like this:

```bash
sudo chown -R :group_id path/to/dir

# in this case:
sudo chown -R :100 path/to/dir
```